# How to prevent Django's response framework from stripping newlines of text files?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to serve a text file in my view, and I can't seem to get Django to respect the newlines in the text file. The code is:

```
    response = TemplateResponse(request, template='dashboard/email_template.txt', mimetype='text/plain', status=200)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=mail_template.txt'
    return response
```

and the file looks something like:

```
    key : {{ user.profile.secret_key }}      # secret key
    message: blah blah                       # Your message
```

When serving the file for download, the two lines are concatenated... When I open the template (email_template.txt) using whatever browser, text editor or IDE, the newlines are respected.

What makes Django (if this has something to do with Django?) concatenate these lines, and how can I prevent it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the lines showing up as concatenated?

Comment: ... And what program are you viewing it in where they show as being concatenated?

Comment: Oh crap - Notepad.exe. I now see that all's well when opening the file in e.g. Chrome... Now, how can I prevent Notepad from concatenating the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually all Notepad's fault, but you can fix it by converting the template to use Windows-style newlines via `unix2dos`.

Comment: As I will be dealing with a lot of (not always very proficient) Windows users, I'd rather not have them use any tool to convert the file. Is there no way this can be handled from within Python?

Comment: You missed part of the answer.